# Google SteppedArea chart - custom tooltips two animated datasets

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

I have a SteppedArea Google chart and I need custom tooltips after animating both of the datasets. But it unfortunately works only in the second dataset. My guess is, that there will be some problem with in my first dataset using

```
data1.addRows([values[1][index]]);
```

and in the second dataset i'm using

```
data1.setValue(index2, 1, values[0][index2][1]);
```

I tried to uset the setValue() function in both datasets, but in the first there is an error, because there are no rows existing when i want to set the value.

I had addRows() in both cases, but had to change due to wrong animation of the second dataset - here's the explanation: [Google charts - animation of stepped chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638458/google-charts-animation-of-stepped-chart?answertab=active#tab-top)

See the fiddle for demonstration: https://codepen.io/jan_cafourek/pen/ybzqRa

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, tooltip role columns may only represent one series column

and must follow the series they represent

to have a tooltip for each series, you will need to add another column to the data table...

```
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn("number", "Year");
data1.addColumn("number", "One");
data1.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'tooltip'});  // <-- tooltip for "One"
data1.addColumn("number", "Two");
data1.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'tooltip'});  // <-- tooltip for "Two"
```

this will change the structure of the array data...

```
var values = [
  [
    [1, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [2, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [3, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [4, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [5, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [6, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [7, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [8, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [9, 1.90, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [10, 1.90, 'tooltip one', null, null]
  ],
  [
    [1, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [2, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [3, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [4, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [5, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [6, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [7, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [8, null, null, 1.00,'tooltip two'],
    [9, null, null, 2.10,'tooltip two'],
    [10, null, null, 2.10,'tooltip two']
  ]
];
```

finally, you can only set one column value at a time using `setValue`,

so need to add another `setValue` for the tooltip...

```
data1.setValue(index2, 1, values[0][index2][1]);
data1.setValue(index2, 2, values[0][index2][2]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  callback: function () {
    drawStepChart();
  },
  packages: ["corechart", "table"]
});

// two sets of values
var values = [
  [
    [1, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [2, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [3, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [4, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [5, 1.22, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [6, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [7, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [8, 1.55, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [9, 1.90, 'tooltip one', null, null],
    [10, 1.90, 'tooltip one', null, null]
  ],
  [
    [1, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [2, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [3, null, null, 2.11,'tooltip two'],
    [4, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [5, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [6, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [7, null, null, 0.80,'tooltip two'],
    [8, null, null, 1.00,'tooltip two'],
    [9, null, null, 2.10,'tooltip two'],
    [10, null, null, 2.10,'tooltip two']
  ]
];

function drawStepChart() {
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn("number", "Year");
  data1.addColumn("number", "One");
  data1.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data1.addColumn("number", "Two");
  data1.addColumn({type:'string', role: 'tooltip'});

  var options = {
    animation: { duration: 50 },
    areaOpacity: 0
  };

  var stepchart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(
    document.getElementById("step")
  );

  var index = 0;
  var index2 = 0;
  var animate1 = function() {
    if (index < values[1].length) {
      data1.addRows([values[1][index]]);
      stepchart.draw(data1, options);
      index++;
    } else {
      if (index2 < values[0].length) {
        data1.setValue(index2, 1, values[0][index2][1]);
        data1.setValue(index2, 2, values[0][index2][2]);
        stepchart.draw(data1, options);
        index2++;
      }
    }
  };
  google.visualization.events.addListener(
    stepchart,
    "animationfinish",
    animate1
  );
  stepchart.draw(data1, options);
  animate1();
}
```

```css
#step {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="step"></div>
```